# Using C# to check if string contains a string in string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search

I want to use C# to check if a string value contains a word in a string array. For example,

```
string stringToCheck = "text1text2text3";

string[] stringArray = { "text1", "someothertext", etc... };

if(stringToCheck.contains stringArray) //one of the items?
{

}
```

How can I check if the string value for 'stringToCheck' contains a word in the  array?

Comment: This blog benchmarks numerous techniques for testing if a string contains a string: http://blogs.davelozinski.com/curiousconsultant/csharp-net-fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-occurs-within-a-string

Comment: This is a prime candidate for a meta question about *highly upvoted incorrect answers*. Is there already one?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
string stringToCheck = "text1";
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "testtest", "test1test2", "test2text1" };
foreach (string x in stringArray)
{
    if (stringToCheck.Contains(x))
    {
        // Process...
    }
}
```

Maybe you are looking for a better solution... Refer to [Anton Gogolev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array/2912483#2912483) which makes use of LINQ.

Comment: Thanks, I modified your code to: if (stringToCheck.Contains(s))
 and it worked.

Comment: I did if (stringArray.Contains(stringToCheck)) and it works great, thanks.

Comment: Don't use this answer use LINQ instead

Comment: Little note to people who do not see **Contains** method on the string array: Check if you have a "using System.Linq;" namespace in your codefile :)

Comment: Linq isn't always available in legacy software.

Comment: .Net 1.x software should be updated to at least .Net 2.x by now.

Comment: The question was to check if the string contains a word a in the string array not the other way around.

Comment: I submitted a modification to fix this answer to be right

Comment: @NetMage, for some reason, reviews keep rejecting the edit suggestions... I have made the necessary updates to the answer today

Comment: using contains is not the best solution here. when checking if the stringToCheck contains x, it would return true for all array items that can be found in text1. so for example stringArray= {"text", "text1", "1" } would all return true. better to use the equal method for an exact match. unless you really just wanted to know if the array item can be found in the string, but the question isn't all that clear tbh.

Answer (score 989):

Here's how:

```
using System.Linq;

if(stringArray.Any(stringToCheck.Contains))

/* or a bit longer: (stringArray.Any(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s))) */
```

This checks if `stringToCheck` contains any one of substrings from `stringArray`. If you want to ensure that it contains all the substrings, change `Any` to `All`:

```
if(stringArray.All(stringToCheck.Contains))
```

Comment: @Spooks Linq To Objects (which is used in the answer's string-check) can be used via LinqBridge on .NET 2.0  
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx

Comment: how would you do this with case invariance?

Comment: @Offler That would be `stringArray.Any(s => s.IndexOf(stringToCheck, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)`

Comment: My edits to this post are always rejected but just to add that you can also use the same syntax of `Any()` on `All()`, i.e. `if(stringArray.All(stringToCheck.Contains))`.

Comment: Handles comparison badly if one of the strings is empty.  So not recommended.

Comment: @Spooks On .NET version 2.0, you can use (with an array type like here) `if (Array.Exists(stringArray, stringToCheck.Contains))` and `if (Array.TrueForAll(stringArray, stringToCheck.Contains))`, respectively. The `List<>` type has methods with the same names, but these are instance methods.

Comment: @AntonGogolev You seem to accidentally swap the roles of `stringToCheck` and `s`?

Comment: if required to compare whole string with each element in string array , then  this code gives incorrect result. e.g. stringToCheck = docx , stringArray [doc, docy].

Comment: @Offler An alternative I see no one mentioning is to just put s as lowercase and .Contains it.

Answer (score 52):

| ⚠️ Note: this does not answer the question asked |
| --- |
| The question asked is "how can I check if a sentence contains any word from a list of words?" |
| This answer checks if a list of words contains one particular word |

## Try this:

No need to use LINQ

```
if (Array.IndexOf(array, Value) >= 0)
{
    //Your stuff goes here
}
```

Comment: Nice! And what benefit could Linq possibly have over Array.IndexOf??

Comment: This doesn't solve the question at all. IndexOf tells you if an array contains an exact match for a string, the original question is if a string contains one of an array of strings, which Linq handles easily.

Comment: I know this comment is late, but just to those who don't know, a string is an array of characters so string types do contain an IndexOf method... so @NetMage it is a possible solution.

Comment: @Blacky Wolf, Did you read the question? Array.IndexOf tells you if an array contains a value, the OP wanted to know if a value contains any member of an array, exactly the opposite of this answer. You could use String.IndexOf with Linq: `stringArray.Any(w => stringToCheck.IndexOf(w) >= 0)` but the Linq answer using String.Contains makes more sense, as that is exactly what is being asked for.

Answer (score 51):

| ⚠️ Note: this does not answer the question asked |
| --- |
| The question asked is "how can I check if a sentence contains any word from a list of words?" |
| This answer checks if a list of words contains one particular word |

Just use the LINQ method:

```
stringArray.Contains(stringToCheck)
```

Comment: Note, that Contains is a extension method and you need to do `using System.Linq;`

Comment: This answer is backwards from the question.

Comment: How has this answer been upvoted so many times? 5 years after the question is asked and the solution is basically reversed of what the question is asking.

Comment: maybe just reverse the variable names it will be ok?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that will call string.Contains, which is different to array.Contains, and string.Contains does not have an overload that accepts an array of string

Answer (score 10):

| ⚠️ Note: this does not answer the question asked |
| --- |
| The question asked is "how can I check if a sentence contains any word from a list of words?" |
| This answer checks if a list of words contains one particular word |

The easiest and simplest way:

```
bool bol = Array.Exists(stringarray, E => E == stringtocheck);
```

Comment: better is stringarray.Exists(entity => entity == stringtocheck)

Comment: I think you cant call exists method directly from string array.Exists method can use directly for list<T>.So should use static method array.exist<T> for string array.check here => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8):

| ⚠️ Note: this does not answer the question asked |
| --- |
| The question asked is "how can I check if a sentence contains any word from a list of words?" |
| This answer checks if a list of words contains one particular word |

```
string strName = "vernie";
string[] strNamesArray = { "roger", "vernie", "joel" };

if (strNamesArray.Any(x => x == strName))
{
   // do some action here if true...
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this perhaps:

```
string stringToCheck = "text1text2text3";
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "text1" };
if (Array.Exists<string>(stringArray, (Predicate<string>)delegate(string s) { 
    return stringToCheck.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1; })) {
    Console.WriteLine("Found!");
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution, since it's a substring check against words in a list instead of an exact match check.

Comment: Nice answer, but wow that is hard to read compared to modern C# even without Linq; also, `String.Contains` might be better than `String.IndexOf` unless you want to ignore case, since Microsoft forgot a two argument `String.Contains` you have to write your own. Consider: `Array.Exists(stringArray, s => stringToCheck.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)`

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own `string.ContainsAny()` and `string.ContainsAll()` methods. As a bonus, I've even thrown in a `string.Contains()` method that allows for case-insensitive comparison, etc.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string source, string value, StringComparison comp)
    {
        return source.IndexOf(value, comp) > -1;
    }

    public static bool ContainsAny(this string source, IEnumerable<string> values, StringComparison comp = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    {
        return values.Any(value => source.Contains(value, comp));
    }

    public static bool ContainsAll(this string source, IEnumerable<string> values, StringComparison comp = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    {
        return values.All(value => source.Contains(value, comp));
    }
}
```

You can test these with the following code:

```
    public static void TestExtensions()
    {
        string[] searchTerms = { "FOO", "BAR" };
        string[] documents = {
            "Hello foo bar",
            "Hello foo",
            "Hello"
        };

        foreach (var document in documents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing: {0}", document);
            Console.WriteLine("ContainsAny: {0}", document.ContainsAny(searchTerms, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            Console.WriteLine("ContainsAll: {0}", document.ContainsAll(searchTerms, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ and a method group would be the quickest and more compact way of doing this.

```
var arrayA = new[] {"element1", "element2"};
var arrayB = new[] {"element2", "element3"};

if (arrayB.Any(arrayA.Contains)) 
    return true;
```

Answer (score 3):

If `stringArray` contains a large number of varied length strings, consider using a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store and search the string array.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool ContainsAny(this string stringToCheck, IEnumerable<string> stringArray)
    {
        Trie trie = new Trie(stringArray);
        for (int i = 0; i < stringToCheck.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (trie.MatchesPrefix(stringToCheck.Substring(i)))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of the `Trie` class

```
public class Trie
{
    public Trie(IEnumerable<string> words)
    {
        Root = new Node { Letter = '\0' };
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            this.Insert(word);
        }
    }

    public bool MatchesPrefix(string sentence)
    {
        if (sentence == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Node current = Root;
        foreach (char letter in sentence)
        {
            if (current.Links.ContainsKey(letter))
            {
                current = current.Links[letter];
                if (current.IsWord)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void Insert(string word)
    {
        if (word == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        Node current = Root;
        foreach (char letter in word)
        {
            if (current.Links.ContainsKey(letter))
            {
                current = current.Links[letter];
            }
            else
            {
                Node newNode = new Node { Letter = letter };
                current.Links.Add(letter, newNode);
                current = newNode;
            }
        }

        current.IsWord = true;
    }

    private class Node
    {
        public char Letter;
        public SortedList<char, Node> Links = new SortedList<char, Node>();
        public bool IsWord;
    }

    private Node Root;
}
```

If all strings in `stringArray` have the same length, you will be better off just using a `HashSet` instead of a `Trie`

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this string stringToCheck, IEnumerable<string> stringArray)
{
    int stringLength = stringArray.First().Length;
    HashSet<string> stringSet = new HashSet<string>(stringArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < stringToCheck.Length - stringLength; ++i)
    {
        if (stringSet.Contains(stringToCheck.Substring(i, stringLength)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

| ⚠️ Note: this does not answer the question asked |
| --- |
| The question asked is "how can I check if a sentence contains any word from a list of words?" |
| This answer checks if a list of words contains one particular word |

```
  stringArray.ToList().Contains(stringToCheck)
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of those solutions are correct, but if you need to check values without case sensitivity:

```
using System.Linq;
...
string stringToCheck = "text1text2text3";
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "someothertext"};

if(stringArray.Any(a=> String.Equals(a, stringToCheck, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) )
{
   //contains
}

if (stringArray.Any(w=> w.IndexOf(stringToCheck, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)>=0))
{
   //contains
}
```

[dotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S3upAB)

Answer (score 2):

LINQ:

arrray.Any(x => word.Equals(x));

This is to see if array contains the word (exact match). Use .Contains for the substring, or whatever other logic you may need to apply instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the same thing as [Anton Gogolev suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array/2912483#2912483) to check if **any item** in `stringArray1` matches **any item** in `stringArray2`:

```
using System.Linq;
if(stringArray1.Any(stringArray2.Contains))
```

And likewise **all items** in stringArray1 match **all items** in stringArray2:

```
using System.Linq;
if(stringArray1.All(stringArray2.Contains))
```

Comment: The second array doesn't have a "Contains" object!

Comment: @Mahmut you need to be using System.Linq namespace.

Comment: @Scott.Net .. Contains property exist on for string type. It's not exist for an Array type.

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar method to the IndexOf [by Maitrey684](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array/17425159#17425159) and the foreach loop of Theomax to create this.  (Note: the first 3 "string" lines are just an example of how you could create an array and get it into the proper format).

If you want to compare 2 arrays, they will be semi-colon delimited, but the last value won't have one after it.  If you append a semi-colon to the string form of the array (i.e. a;b;c becomes a;b;c;), you can match using "x;" no matter what position it is in:

```
bool found = false;
string someString = "a-b-c";
string[] arrString = someString.Split('-');
string myStringArray = arrString.ToString() + ";";

foreach (string s in otherArray)
{
    if (myStringArray.IndexOf(s + ";") != -1) {
       found = true;
       break;
    }
}

if (found == true) { 
    // ....
}
```

Comment: But [Maitrey684 does not answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array/17425159#17425159) the question(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Point was they were on the right track, to use `IndexOf`, and was simply giving credit to where my idea stemmed from. In other words, you can use the code I supplied to take the array, iterate over it, then do the `IndexOf` (like Maitrey684 said, sort of) to tell if it contains your value.

Answer (score 1):

| ⚠️ Note: this does not answer the question asked |
| --- |
| The question asked is "how can I check if a sentence contains any word from a list of words?" |
| This answer checks if a list of words contains one particular word |

I would use [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), but it still can be done through:

```
new[] {"text1", "text2", "etc"}.Contains(ItemToFind);
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the previous answers, for the **IgnoreCase** check, use:

```
stringArray.Any(s => stringToCheck.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the index of the match with that also? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, the above answers did not work. I was checking for a string in an array and assigning it to a boolean value. I modified [Anton Gogolev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array/2912483#2912483) and removed the `Any()` method and put the `stringToCheck` inside the `Contains()` method.

```
bool isContain = stringArray.Contains(stringToCheck);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=netframework-4.8) or [FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=netframework-4.8) methods of the [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
if(Array.Find(stringArray, stringToCheck.Contains) != null) 
{ 
}
```

```
if(Array.FindIndex(stringArray, stringToCheck.Contains) != -1) 
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution as well.

```
string[] nonSupportedExt = { ".3gp", ".avi", ".opus", ".wma", ".wav", ".m4a", ".ac3", ".aac", ".aiff" };
        
bool valid = Array.Exists(nonSupportedExt,E => E == ".Aac".ToLower());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String[] val = { "helloword1", "orange", "grape", "pear" };
String sep = "";
string stringToCheck = "word1";

bool match = String.Join(sep,val).Contains(stringToCheck);
bool anothermatch = val.Any(s => s.Contains(stringToCheck));
```

Comment: Does this even compile? At least the use of "String" and "string" is inconsistent (thus the weird syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 0):

| ⚠️ Note: this does not answer the question asked |
| --- |
| The question asked is "how can I check if a sentence contains any word from a list of words?" |
| This answer checks if a list of words contains one particular word |

I use the following in a console application to check for arguments

```
var sendmail = args.Any( o => o.ToLower() == "/sendmail=true");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string [] lines = {"text1", "text2", "etc"};

bool bFound = lines.Any(x => x == "Your string to be searched");
```

*bFound* is set to true if the searched string is matched with any element of array 'lines'.

Answer (score 0):

```
string word = "XRC"; // Try also with word = null; 

string[] myWords = { "CUS", "CT", "NMS", "RX", "RUS", "VUS", "XRC", null };

if (myWords.Contains(word))
    Console.WriteLine("1. if: contains the string");
    
if (myWords.Any(word.Contains))
    Console.WriteLine("2. if: contains the string, but null elements throws an exception");
    
if (myWords.Any(x => x.Equals(word)))
    Console.WriteLine("3. if: contains the string, but null elements throws an exception ");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Example: To check if the field contains any of the words in the array. To check if the field (someField) contains any of the words in the array.

```
String[] val = { "helloword1", "orange", "grape", "pear" };

Expression<Func<Item, bool>> someFieldFilter = i => true;

someFieldFilter = i => val.Any(s => i.someField.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public bool ContainAnyOf(string word, string[] array) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (word.Contains(array[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
string stringToCheck = "text1text2text3";
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "text1" };

var t = lines.ToList().Find(c => c.Contains(stringToCheck));
```

It will return you the line with the first incidence of the text that you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution that does not require any LINQ:

```
String.Join(",", array).Contains(Value + ",");
```

Comment: What if one of the values in the array contains your delimiter?

Answer (score -1):

```
int result = Array.BinarySearch(list.ToArray(), typedString, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. There isn't any need for a loop..

```
string stringToCheck = "text1";
List<string> stringList = new List<string>() { "text1", "someothertext", "etc.." };
if (stringList.Exists(o => stringToCheck.Contains(o)))
{

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I used the following code to check if the string contained any of the items in the string array:

```
foreach (string s in stringArray)
{
    if (s != "")
    {
        if (stringToCheck.Contains(s))
        {
            Text = "matched";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sets `Text = "matched"` as many times as `stringToCheck` contains substrings of `stringArray`. You may want to put a `break` or `return` after the assignment.

Answer (score -3):

Three options demonstrated.  I prefer to find the third as the most concise.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
    string req = "PUT";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}).Any(s => req.Contains(s))) {
        Console.WriteLine("one.1.A");  // IS TRUE
    }
    req = "XPUT";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}).Any(s => req.Contains(s))) {
        Console.WriteLine("one.1.B"); // IS TRUE
    }
    req = "PUTX";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}).Any(s => req.Contains(s))) {
        Console.WriteLine("one.1.C");  // IS TRUE
    }
    req = "UT";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}).Any(s => req.Contains(s))) {
        Console.WriteLine("one.1.D"); // false
    }
    req = "PU";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}).Any(s => req.Contains(s))) {
        Console.WriteLine("one.1.E"); // false
    }
    req = "POST";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}).Any(s => req.Contains(s))) {
        Console.WriteLine("two.1.A"); // IS TRUE
    }
    req = "ASD";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}).Any(s => req.Contains(s))) {
        Console.WriteLine("three.1.A");  // false
    }


    Console.WriteLine("-----");
    req = "PUT";
    if (Array.IndexOf((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}), req) >= 0)  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.2.A"); // IS TRUE
    }
    req = "XPUT";
    if (Array.IndexOf((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}), req) >= 0)  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.2.B"); // false
    }
    req = "PUTX";
    if (Array.IndexOf((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}), req) >= 0)  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.2.C"); // false
    }
    req = "UT";
    if (Array.IndexOf((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}), req) >= 0)  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.2.D"); // false
    }
    req = "PU";
    if (Array.IndexOf((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}), req) >= 0)  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.2.E"); // false
    }
    req = "POST";
    if (Array.IndexOf((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}), req) >= 0)  {
        Console.WriteLine("two.2.A");  // IS TRUE
    }
    req = "ASD";
    if (Array.IndexOf((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}), req) >= 0)  {
        Console.WriteLine("three.2.A");  // false
    }

    Console.WriteLine("-----");
    req = "PUT";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}.Contains(req)))  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.3.A"); // IS TRUE
    }
    req = "XPUT";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}.Contains(req)))  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.3.B");  // false
    }
    req = "PUTX";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}.Contains(req)))  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.3.C");  // false
    }
    req = "UT";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}.Contains(req)))  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.3.D");  // false
    }
    req = "PU";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}.Contains(req)))  {
        Console.WriteLine("one.3.E");  // false
    }
    req = "POST";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}.Contains(req)))  {
        Console.WriteLine("two.3.A");  // IS TRUE
    }
    req = "ASD";
    if ((new string[] {"PUT", "POST"}.Contains(req)))  {
        Console.WriteLine("three.3.A");  // false
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second two options don't even do the same thing at the first one.