# Can we have the OR operator in the string variable in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using C# to check if string contains a string in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array)

Can we have the multiple strings in a single string variable using logical OR operator(|) in asp.net ?

```
string _Text = "";
string _str = "abc" | "xyz" | "123";
if(_Text.Contains(_str))
{
    foo("_str");
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you do this in any other language?

Comment: Have you tryed the code your self? Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: @PoweRoy Python allows `"abc" or "xyz" or "123"` with the result `"abc"`, because every non-empty string is evaluated to true. http://ideone.com/STyWh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array

Comment: its not working, rather array or some other collection will do, but still i want to know is there any way out ... ?

Comment: @halex: I mean 'can you do this in any other language with the desired result', compiled doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @PoweRoy Ah ok. Just wanted to show proof of concept of this one line in python :)

Comment: @halex: its not working, thats why i was asking ...

Comment: @krishn, what whould be the meaning of "aaaaa" | "bbb"?

Comment: @peer: let me rephrase myself, is there any way out to execute function foo(_str), with the same _str value(instead of other _str values) which satisfies the if condition, using string variable ... though we can do the same with an array ... hope i made myself clear.

Answer (score 3):

use regex `Regex.IsMatch(_Text, @"^(abc)|(xyz)|(123)$")`

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't, but you can work around:

```
string _Text = "abc"
var _str = new[] {"abc", "xyz", "123"};

if(_str.Any(s => _Text.Contains(s))
{
     foo(_Text);
}
```

Comment: @peer: you changed the differently, roll back

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear to me what you want to do. The or (|) isn't going to work anyway. Do you need something like this?

```
string haystack = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string[] needles = {"fox", "the", "dog"};

foreach (var n in needles)
{
    if (haystack.Contains(n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found in '{1}'", n, haystack);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use any sort of container for that (array/list/etc).

Answer (score 0):

No it can't be done your way. But How about using an array

```
string _Text = "";
string[] _str = {"abc" , "xyz" , "123"};
if(_str.Contains(_Text))
{
    foo(_Text);
}
```

Comment: @Cuong Le: this code works fine, I would rename the _str variable. You should try to compile your own code, assigning a array to a string will give you a error.

Comment: @peer: Right. The Regex answer of Burning_LEGION is doing what my answer is doing but with regex.

Comment: @peer: thanks, edited, what if text = "abcdsd"?

Comment: @CuongLe: Still compile and work. It will not go inside if statement.

Comment: I fixed both of your code samples, however the main question whould be what the meaning of "aa" | "b" whould be. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @peer: why LINQ when Contains works?

Comment: You are correct, the variable name confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Both operands have to be booleans:

[Logical OR Operator: ||](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8.aspx)

"The logical OR operator (||) returns the boolean value true if either or both operands is true and returns false otherwise. The operands are implicitly converted to type bool prior to evaluation, and the result is of type bool. Logical OR has left-to-right associativity."