# how to do a contains on an array of strings?

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder

I am using a predicate builder class and I need to invoke the contains method on an array of strings so in the code below instead of radio I would be passing in an array of strings:

```
wherePredicate = wherePredicate.Or(m => m.MediaType.Contains("Radio"));
```

the full code section:

```
if (param.iMediaGroupID > 0)
{
    var wherePredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MediaChannelModel>();

    var ss = new NeptuneRepository<Lookup_MediaTypes>();
    var mediagroups = ss.FindWhere(m => m.MediaGroupID == param.iMediaGroupID).Select(m => m.Name);
    //problem area
    wherePredicate = wherePredicate.Or(m => mediagroups.Contains(m.MediaType));
    predicate = predicate.And(wherePredicate);
}
```

`mediaGroups` is: `["Radio","Tv","Magazine"]`

If `m.MediaType` is any of these values then the predicate is true.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: You want to know if MediaType is part of an string array? Is this corrrect?

Comment: this might give you a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array

Comment: isn't it just `m => mediaGroups.Any(g => m.MediaType == g)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you want something like:

```
wherePredicate = wherePredicate.Or(m => array.Contains(m.MediaType));
```

Or perhaps:

```
wherePredicate = wherePredicate.Or(m => array.Any(x => m.MediaType.Contains(x)));
```

If neither of those are what you're after, please clarify your requirements.

EDIT: The problem you're now facing is that you're not *actually* asking whether an array contains the value. You're asking whether a *query* contains a value. If you change it to an actual array, you may well find it works:

```
var mediagroups = ss.FindWhere(m => m.MediaGroupID == param.iMediaGroupID)
                    .Select(m => m.Name)
                    .ToArray();
```

However, if these are querying the same database, you'd be better off trying to do this in some kind of join.

Comment: Jon, what is Or method here? Is it `BitArray.Or` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül: No, it's presumably a `PredicateBuilder` class which the OP is already using.

Comment: Hi, Im getting this error: "The specified linq expression contains refrences to queries with different contexts", I have also included the  whole problem section.

Comment: Hi Jon, Could you help me convert the two contains methods to a Join, this currently causes a timeout exception because of the contains being too slow in EF5. I have included the table structures in the edited question.

Comment: @xerxes: I think it would be better to start a new question about that, to be honest.

Comment: I did but noone has been able to help, could you have a look please, its here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472773/how-to-use-a-join-in-linq-instead-of-contains?noredirect=1#comment25391752_17472773

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet's answer worked perfectly for me.  I had been struggling to make the .Contains search for a substring in a string array against the database, rather than try to find a substring in a single C# string object.  Thank you!

Here's the modified code that worked for me:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ClientXMemberDetail>();
predicate = predicate.Or(x => strArrselectedCustomMemberNumbers.Any<string>(y => x.MemberID.Contains(y)));
CustomSearchMembersAlreadyMatched = ClientXContext.ClientXMemberDetails
                        .AsExpandable()
                            .Where(predicate)
                            .ToList()
                            .Select(r => r.MemberID.ToString()).ToList();
```

(ClientXContext above is an instance of the ObjectContext class, strArrselectedCustomMemberNumbers is a string array, ClientXMemberDetails is ObjectSet, where ClientXMemberDetail is the EntityObject)

Edit: Anonymized my client's name