# C# - using string contains with string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a question regarding C#, strings and arrays. 
I've searched for similar questions at stack overflow, but could not find any answers.

My problem:

I have a string array, which contains words / wordparts to check file names. If all of these strings in the array matches, the word is "good".

```
String[] StringArray = new String[] { "wordpart1", "wordpart2", ".txt" };
```

Now I want to check if all these strings are a part of a filename. If this checkresult is true, I want to do something with this file.
How can I do that?

I already tried different approaches, but all doesn't work.

i.e.

```
e.Name.Contains(StringArray)
```

etc.

I want to avoid to use a loop (for, foreach) to check all wordparts. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar question: [Using C# to check if string contains a string in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array)

This uses LINQ:

> ```
> if(stringArray.Any(stringToCheck.Contains))
> ```
>
> This checks if stringToCheck contains any one of substrings from
>   stringArray. If you want to ensure that it contains all the
>   substrings, change Any to All:
>
> ```
> if(stringArray.All(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s)))
> ```

Answer (score 5):

> Now I want to check if all these strings are a part of a filename. If this checkresult is true, I want to do something with this file. How can I do that?

Thanks to `LINQ` and method groups conversions, it can be easily done like this:

```
bool check = StringArray.All(yourFileName.Contains);
```