# .Contains() on file contents not working as expected

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an ai. I have got it to write a topic with information to a text file but cant get it to read. this is what i have so far. Any ideas on why it isnt working?

```
string information = "blank";
Console.WriteLine("Hello my name is Lou-C.");
Console.WriteLine("What is yours?");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, What do you want to talk about?", name);
string topic = Console.ReadLine();
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\simon.light\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Lou-c\Lou-c\information.txt");
if (lines.Contains("beat"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Aaahh, {0}, I have heard of this before");
    Console.WriteLine("Tell me what you know about this");
    information = Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}? I don't think i have come across this before.", topic);
Console.WriteLine("Tell me about it");
information = Console.ReadLine();
}

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\simon.light\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Lou-c\Lou-c\information.txt", true))
{
    file.WriteLine("${0} - %{1} - by {2}", topic, information, name);
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on "isn't working"?

Comment: Based on his question and code I think he is referencing this line as causing him trouble: ` string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\simon.light\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Lou-c\Lou-c\information.txt");` . OP can you verify?

Comment: Why do you use `File.ReadAllLines` for reading but `StreamWriter.WriteLine` for writing? Why not `File.AppendLine`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with AI, so I'm going to update the title and remove the tag.

Comment: Additionally, the logic seems wrong. `topic` is read in from the command line, but then you check if `"beat"` exists in the file, rather than if `topic` does.

Comment: That is not how you check contents of a string array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array

Comment: Btw. are you aware that `lines.Contains("beat")` will only be true if the file contains at least one line with `"beat"` *and nothing else*. Or did you mean to look if any of the lines contains `"beat"` instead?

Comment: `lines.any((line)=>line.contains("beat"));`

Comment: isnt working:every time i input data that is already in the txt file is dosent complete the if statement but the else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for any line that contains "beat"

```
if (lines.Any(s => s.Contains("beat")))
```

However, if you used `ReadAllText` then your contains would work!

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(...);
if (text.Contains("beat"))
```