# Check string if it contain any of string array value, then get the substring

Tags: c#, arrays, string

This may be a sub-question to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array/18455074). I want to check the string against an array of string or list.
Example

```
string address = "1st nice ave 1st floor";    
//For now, I'm getting the list from a text file but could move to use an EF    
List<string> streetType = File.ReadLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"streetType.csv")
                              .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
                              .Select(y => y.ToLowerInvariant())
                              .ToArray();
```

the purpose is to strip the extra address details after the avenue, the csv file contains all USPS accepted street type.

This is what I have now

```
//this only returns boolean value, I got this from the SO above
streetType.Any(testaddress.ToLower().Contains);

//I also have this
Array.Exists<string>(streetType, (Predicate<string>)delegate (string s)
{         
   return testaddress.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;       
});
```

I've been looking for hours how to resolve this then I came across the SO question which is exactly what I also want but I need to get the substring to for stripping.

If there's a linq query, that would be awesome. The only way I can think of doing this is with foreach and inner if.

**Example of the array values**

- ave
- avenue
- pkwy

**Update:**

Here is my answer, I forgot to mention that the array lookup needs to match the exact string from the address string. I ended up using regex. This is the expanded/modified answer of @giladGreen.

```
  var result = from item in streetTypes
                         let index = Regex.Match(address.ToLowerInvariant(), @"\b" + item.ToLowerInvariant() + @"\b")
                         where index.Success == true
                         select address.ToLowerInvariant().Substring(0, index.Index + item.Length);
```

Can somebody convert this to lambda expression? I tried I failed.

Thank you all

Comment: Please show some example lines of data from the csv file and desired output. It will make it easier to understand

Comment: Just as a warning, linq to SQL from EF may not work with some complex linq queries.

Comment: Still not clear what you want. Given a collection of values you want to find if they exist in a given string and if so then what?

Comment: @GiladGreen I search the string with the any of the values in the array then if found, I want to get the substring, so I can remove all other extra details after the street type.

Comment: OP wants to check if a string contains any value from the array, if yes, wants that value i.e. substring from the array too.

Comment: So you want from the beginning until the index of that streetType if present?

Comment: Please replace your file access code with a simple `List<string>` initialized with data. In other words, provide a *reproducible*, copy-pasteable sample that we can all use so we're on the same page.

Comment: @GiladGreen yessir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IndexOf` to understand of item is present in `address` and if so to return the string after it:

```
var result = from item in streetType
             let index = address.IndexOf(item)
             where index != -1
             select address.SubString(0, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to simply `Split` each address on the `streetType` list, and then take the first item (at `index[0]`) from the resulting array:

```
addresses = addresses
    .Select(address => address.Split(streetTypes.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.None)[0])
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be inclined to do something like this:

```
string[] markers = "ave avenue pkwy".Split();
string address = "1st nice ave 1st floor";

var result = markers
            .Select((marker, index) => new
            {
                markerIndex = index,
                addressPosition = address.IndexOf(marker)
            })
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.addressPosition != -1);


// returns { markerIndex = 0, addressPosition = 9 }
```

Then `result` is an object that is either **null** (if the marker is not found) or is an object containing both `markerIndex`, which tells you which marker was found first, and `addressPosition` which tells you the character at which the marker string was found.