# Filtering Listbox by content from text file

Tags: c#

Can someone explain why the following code it isn't filtering?

```
private void LoadAppointments()
{
    // load all "Routine" appointments into the listbox
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\appointments.txt");

    string filter = "Routine";

    // this part is not working. It isn't filtering by only showing 
    // "Routine" appointments in the listbox.
    if (lines.Contains(filter))
    {
        listAppts.Items.Add(lines);
    }

    listAppts.Items.AddRange(lines);  
    // if I leave this out, nothing gets loaded, but if I add this 
    // line, everything gets loaded without being filtered.
}
```

Comment: Here is the contents of the dummy text file:

Charlie Brown, Thursday 21 February 2019, 10:45 AM, Nina Booth, Routine
Peppermint Patty, Thursday 21 February 2019, 2:30 PM, Nina Booth, Cancelled
Lucy Schroeder, Thursday 21 February 2019, 11:30 AM, Nina Booth, Routine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C# to check if string contains a string in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array)

Comment: `string[].Contains()` is going to look if your string value, VERBATIM, is in the array, not if any of the strings _themselves_ include your filter value.

Comment: I don't see any filter, clarify what you want to do please

Comment: @gunr2171 - Thank you. I'll check on a better method to filter. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Pliskin - if any of the lines in the text file contain the word "Routine" then I want that line in the listbox, but only those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void LoadAppointments()
{
    // load all "Routine" appointments into the listbox
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\appointments.txt");

    string filter = "Routine";

    var filteredLines = lines.Where(line => line.Contains(filter)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this:

```
if (lines.Contains(filter))
{
    listAppts.Items.Add(lines);
}
```

The contains function returns true, if any of the lines matches, in its entirety, "Routine". What you really need is the list of lines where a substring of that line has "Routine". Eg.

```
List<string> res = lines.Where(x => x.Contains(filter)).ToList();
listAppts.Items.Addrange(res);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate it. I didn't realize that it was looking for a verbatim match instead of a substring.